# Pascal Case in C# properties

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style, naming-conventions, pascalcasing

Which one do you choose and why:

```
public class User
{
    public long UserID { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
}
```

And also as parameters:

```
public void DoSomething(long userId) { }
public void DoSomething(long userID) { }
```

Comment: @CodyGray: Oh so many duplicates..but why did I get no result by searching in SO using `[c#] ID Id` :( at least no result on the first page.

Comment: No idea. I use Google for searching. I think they invented it, at least the working version. One problem is that some people label/tag their questions with [tag:c#], others label/tag with [tag:.net]. There's no real consistency for questions that aren't actually about the language but give incidental code samples in a particular dialect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) make it very clear to choose `UserId` and `userId` respectively (emphasis mine):

> The two abbreviations that can be used in identifiers are ID and OK. **In Pascal-cased identifiers they should appear as Id, and Ok.** If used as the first word in a camel-cased identifier, they should appear as id and ok, respectively.

Comment: But to be honest, I've asked a few teammates(all Chinese), all of us feel strange to `UserId`, we know the naming conentions, but it really feels bad. It's a weird understanding to all of us(maybe only to Chinese programmers? LOL)

Comment: Of course, the framework methods don't all follow this internally. And thanks to IntelliSense, it hardly matters which one you pick.

Comment: @DannyChen: For what it's worth, I'm not Chinese and `UserId` looks ugly/wrong to me, too. I generally make exceptions for two-letter acronyms/abbreviations because it hardly hurts readability.

Comment: If you get resharper you can choose convensions and it will raise warnings or errors if you are keen to conform to the convesions.

Comment: @Dessus: You don't have to shell out the money for Resharper to get annoying nags. StyleCop will do the same thing for free, and it's even customizable.

Answer (score 0):

For Id, its short for Identifier, and not an acronym; It makes sense to make it lower case after the first letter.

Comment: Even HTML, URL and URI, as acronyms, in Pascal case are capitalized as `Html`, `Url` and `Uri` respectively.

Comment: Yea but for his case it wouldn't make sense under any scheme